# Converting numbered day of year to Month on the X axis for NDVI time series analysis for a range of years

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, time-series, chart

I am working on an NDVI time-series series analysis to detect incidence pests. Timeseries generated by landcover is okay as I am using ui.Chart.image.series function.

The problem I have is with the second chart in which I am using ui.Chart.image.doySeriesByYear function to chart my time series for 2017-2021.

I am looking for help on aggregating the day of year to Month on the X-axis. I have tried but I am getting errors (commented out section).

Here is the link to the script: https://code.earthengine.google.com/3ed6b54e8b2476e518948bb834a2216a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem was in using the wrong feature collection for plotting. Instead of using scaledNDVI it should be your chart3 object.

```
var chart3 = ui.Chart.feature.groups({
  features: chart3, // scaledNDVI
  xProperty: 'month',
  yProperty: 'NDVI',
  seriesProperty: 'year'
})
  
print(chart3)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/b5911a70b9c4b64b8b8c8b8a7bbc6904

Comment: Yes, the error was naming my collection. Thanks for pointing it out. It now works